# For loop <p> tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, loops

I need to loop using jQuery. Sometimes my query returns more than one row, so I want to check if the query returned more than one. I want to view all outputs in `p` tags (one by one). I wrote my code and it gives only the last row in my query. How can I return all rows in `<p>` tags? What is the error in my code?

```html
 <p id="prodDeccarea"> </p>
```

```js
$("#slsNo").keyup(function () {
    $("#hsCode").val(null);
    $("#slsiUnit").val(null);
    var slsNo = $("#slsNo").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProd/' + slsNo,
        success: function (result) {
            var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
            var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
            for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
                if (1 < jdata.length) {
                    var td1 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                    var td2 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                    var td3 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                    $("#prodDeccarea").html("Your product catagory is " + jdata[x].itemDesc + ".");

                } else {
                    var td1 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                    var td2 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                    var td3 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                    $("#hsCode").val(td2);
                    $("#prodDeccarea").html("Your product catagory is " + td1 + ".");
                    if (td3 == "1") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT1");
                    }
                    if (td3 == "2") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT2");
                    }
                    if (td3 == "3") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT3");
                    }
                    if (td3 == "4") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT4");
                    }
                    if (td3 == "5") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT5");
                    }
                    if (td3 == "6") {
                        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT6");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: What's the reason for serializing and immediately deserializing an object (`var jString = JSON.stringify(result); var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);`)?

Comment: ah... I use it doesn't affect anything.. I will remove it... If you can please give me some answer...

Comment: Try $("#prodDeccarea").append("<p>Your product catagory is " + jdata[x].itemDesc + ".</p>");

Comment: @angel.bonev ...The cord works very well.

Comment: @vidarshana you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

## You have some issues in your code

**Let's analyze them :-)**

You're using a condition when the array `jdata`'s length === 1 within the `for-loop`.  Move that logic outside from the `for-loop`.

```
for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
    if (1 < jdata.length) { 
    ^
```

You're overriding the content of your previously call of function `.html(...)`.  Therefore, you're losing the previous HTML.

```
$("#prodDeccarea").html("Your product catagory is " + td1 + ".");
                       ^
```

You're stringifying an already JSON String, just parse it.

```
var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                   ^
```

You have multiple conditions to set a value according to tdr3's value.  Just use that value and set it to the element.  I.e: `$("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT" + td3);`

```
if (td3 == "1") { <- Here
    $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT1");
} 
if (td3 == "2") { <- Here, and so on
    $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT2");
}
```

## Look at this code snippet with those fixes

```js
$("#slsNo").keyup(function() {
  $("#hsCode").val(null);
  $("#slsiUnit").val(null);
  var slsNo = $("#slsNo").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProd/' + slsNo,
    success: function(result) {
      var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
      var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);

      if (jdata.length === 1) {
        var td1 = jdata[0].itemDesc;
        var td2 = jdata[0].hsCode;
        var td3 = jdata[0].slsiUnit;
        $("#hsCode").val(td2);
        $("#prodDeccarea").html("Your product catagory is " + td1 + ".");
        $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT" + td3);
        
        return;
      }

      for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
        var td1 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
        var td2 = jdata[x].hsCode;
        var td3 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
        var $prodDeccarea = $("#prodDeccarea");
        $prodDeccarea.html($prodDeccarea.html() + '<p>' + "Your product catagory is " + jdata[x].itemDesc + "." + "</p>");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use each method  https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$("p").each(function(element) {
  console.log(element.text);
});
```

This will print out the contents of all p elements in your code.

Comment: This seems unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: @charsi  how my cord inclue to this function

Comment: @charsi .... The cord works... I do something append() ... then it works,,,

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProd/' + slsNo,
     dataType: "json",//if you return json data you don't need var jString = JSON.stringify(result);var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
     beforeSend: function () {
       $("#prodDeccarea").html("");//this will clear previous results 
     },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, e) {//this will loop through all the results
            $("#prodDeccarea").append("<p>RESULT " + i + " : ".JSON.stringify(e));//this will add to the at the end of #prodDeccarea
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

guess the problem is here,you didn't accumulate;

```
    $("#slsNo").keyup(function () {
        $("#hsCode").val(null);
        $("#slsiUnit").val(null);
        var slsNo = $("#slsNo").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/ViewProd/' + slsNo,
            success: function (result) {
                var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);
                for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {
                    if (1 < jdata.length) {
                        var td1 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                        var td2 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        var td3 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                        //accumulate
                        $("#prodDeccarea").html($("#prodDeccarea").html()+"Your product catagory is " + jdata[x].itemDesc + ".");


                    } else {
                        var td1 = jdata[x].itemDesc;
                        var td2 = jdata[x].hsCode;
                        var td3 = jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                        $("#hsCode").val(td2);
                        $("#prodDeccarea").html("Your product catagory is " + td1 + ".");
                        if (td3 == "1") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT1");
                        }
                        if (td3 == "2") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT2");
                        }
                        if (td3 == "3") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT3");
                        }
                        if (td3 == "4") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT4");
                        }
                        if (td3 == "5") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT5");
                        }
                        if (td3 == "6") {
                            $("#slsiUnit").val("UNIT6");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Why use two selectors on the same element to build a HTML string when you can just use `append()`?

Comment: @xianshenglu .. I'm new to jquery ... If you can please send me the modified cord... I cant understand that theory.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not familiar to jquery,actually i want to use innerHTM+=,,,,,

Comment: Thank you for you all ... The cord works... I use append()

Comment: the reason is didn't accumulate?